# What is this "/trackBannerM" that appeared in my Google Analytics site content report?

Tags: google-analytics

yesterday this "/trackBannerM" page appeared in my Google Analytics Site Content reports.

This page doesn't exist on my website and there are no broken link pointing to it. I have checked my website logfiles and there are no GET requests for this url.

Do you have any clue on this mistery?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely some kind of virtual pageview. If you execute:

In Classic Analytics (ga.js)

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/trackBannerM']);
```

Or in Universal Analytics (analytics.js)

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/trackBannerM');
```

This page will show up in GA even though it doesn't exist. This is called a virtual pageview.

You just have to find out where this call placed and by who. Maybe you are using some kind of widget that injects code in your site and is tracking banners using this method.